# Очистить все данные работы WebView в приложении на UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, mobile-development

Есть приложение в которой происходит авторизация через **WebView**. После того как удаляю cookies таким вот методом:

```
HttpCookieCollection cookieCollection = cookieManager.GetCookies(new Uri(url));
            foreach (HttpCookie cookie in cookieCollection)
                cookieManager.DeleteCookie(cookie);
```

При повторном открытии той же страницы (c целью входа нового пользователя) содержавшую **WebView** как и положено страница запрашивает снова логин и пароль, но при нажатии кнопки отправить можно вводить что угодно он перенаправит на страницу уже "залогиненного" перед этим пользователя. При этом можно даже не вводить пароль и тд. Не выдается так же ошибок об вводе не правильных данных, типа не правильных логин и пароль. Ежели провернуть это же в обычном браузере срабатывает как нужно. 
Какие есть еще методы очистки **cookies** и ***любых других файлов работы*** WebView?

```
<Page
    x:Class="VKAuto.AuthPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VKAuto"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView x:Name="OAuth"  MinWidth="300" MinHeight="400"
                 NavigationCompleted="OAuth_NavigationCompleted" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Считаю это проблемой именно WebView , так как если закрыть все сессии из аккаунта, то при попытке авторизовался, все сработает отлично, но опять таки оно оставит этого пользователя до сброса сессии.

Comment: [Этот ответ](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b2050b2-dd5d-44a4-bad9-d5e0802fd199/uwpuwp-webview-clear-cookies?forum=wpdevelop) рекомендует удалить объект `WebView` из UI и пересоздать его на том же месте снова.

Comment: Читал о таком, но на UWP не знаю как это делать, Dispose или подобное отсутствует или я не знаю как, на MSDN ничего не вычитал. Не поможете?

Comment: Никакого Dispose по идее не нужно. Как выглядит ваш XAML, в котором определяется WebView?

Comment: к сожалению могу поделится только так : https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap3_qbHglOgIowql-3rvNzY3_kda

Comment: Можно ж вставить в вопрос (сделал). Ну, попробуйте в том месте, где нужно убрать cookie, что-то такое: `var grid = OAuth.Parent; grid.Children.Remove(OAuth); OAuth.NavigationCompleted -=  OAuth_NavigationCompleted; OAuth = new WebView(); OAuth.MinWidth = 300; OAuth.MinHeight = 400; OAuth.NavigationCompleted += OAuth_NavigationCompleted; grid.Children.Add(OAuth);`

Comment: @VladD Вот, что говорит студия https://pp.vk.me/c604530/v604530531/177a9/W7hRbQ445x8.jpg

Comment: а если `var grid = (Grid)OAuth.Parent;`?

Comment: Сделал так, добавил Name для Grid и попытался использовать совет выше:
            var grid = MainGrid;
            grid.Children.Remove(OAuth);
            OAuth.NavigationCompleted -= OAuth_NavigationCompleted;
            OAuth = new WebView();
            OAuth.MinWidth = 300;
            OAuth.MinHeight = 400;
            OAuth.NavigationCompleted += OAuth_NavigationCompleted;
            grid.Children.Add(OAuth);
НО к сожалению ситуация та же.

Comment: А в какой момент вы это делаете?

Comment: Собственно при каждом вызове страницы в событии Page_Loaded. Так как страница AuthPage с WebView нужна только для авторизации, соответственно всегда должно обеспечиваться возможность входа любого пользователя.

Comment: Окей, странно. А если скомбинировать с вашим кодом, который в вопросе?

Comment: Можно подробнее, по поводу скомбинировать? Может я уже это делал или наоборот делал не так.

Comment: Смотрите, во втором комментарии есть ссылка. Там вроде бы замена UI-элемента помогла. Но у автора того вопроса была ещё попытки удалить cookie. Что-то из этого сработало. Вот я и предлагаю, делать и то и другое, то есть перед заменой UI-элемента ещё попробовать почистить cookie.

Comment: Использовал Ваш совет вместе с уже упомянутым способом очистки Cookies. Результат тот же.

Comment: А вот это не работает? `await Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync();` В UWP добавили как раз метод очистки кэша и временных данных.

Comment: Не пробовал. Но если быть честным. Я как и любой начинающий изучающий пошел не по дороге а через лес. Объясню почему. У меня не происходил разлогин для vk.com  аккаунта. В итоге я решил чистить все. Уже сейчас я нашел причину и все оказалось НАМНОГО ПОЩЕ. Просто я забыл удалить куки и от login.vk.com

Answer (score 2):

Нашел такой вот способ. Для его работы должен быть разрешен не безопасный код.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet =System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]

public static extern bool InternetSetOption(int hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);

    private static unsafe void SuppressWininetBehavior()
    {
        /* SOURCE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
            * INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR (81):
            *      A general purpose option that is used to suppress behaviors on a process-wide basis. 
            *      The lpBuffer parameter of the function must be a pointer to a DWORD containing the specific behavior to suppress. 
            *      This option cannot be queried with InternetQueryOption. 
            *      
            * INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST (3):
            *      Suppresses the persistence of cookies, even if the server has specified them as persistent.
            *      Version:  Requires Internet Explorer 8.0 or later.
            */

        int option = (int)3/* INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST*/;
        int* optionPtr = &option;

        bool success = InternetSetOption(0, 81/*INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR*/, new IntPtr(optionPtr), sizeof(int));
        if (!success)
        {

        }
    }
```

Вызов данной функции поставил сразу же после инициализации страницы.

```
public AuthPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SuppressWininetBehavior();
       }
```

Брал вот тут: [Источник использованного кода](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.ru/2013/02/c-winforms-webbrowser-clear-all-cookies.html)

Comment: Работоспособность метода на Windows Phone не проверялась, пока что. На Desktop работает отлично.

Comment: Проверил.  Не работает. Решение только для desktop.